# Having trouble supplying two variables to a loop in bash

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, variables

I am new to bash. I need some help with loops.

I want a loop to read the variables from two different files and perform an action. For example: I want to supply two files to the 'for' loop -

file1 contains the first names (each word in new line)

```
Peter
Mary
```

file2 contains second names (each word in a new line)

```
Parker
Jane
```

and i want to achieve something like this -

```
for i in $(cat file1), j in $(cat file2)

do

echo $i $j 

done
```

Expected output:

```
Peter Parker 
Mary Jane
```

If someone could tell me how to achieve the above in bash that will be great.

TIA

Comment: A shortcut: `paste -d ' ' file1 file2`

Comment: You can do `paste -d'|' file1 file2 | while IFS='|' read f1line f2line; do echo "$f1line $f2line"; done`.